# Adding a parameter to a Facebook Instant Games URL, to access it later in the game

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-instant-games

We would like to add a parameter to our InstantGame link http://m.me/PageTitle?game=GameTitle**&PARAMETER=VALUE**, which we want to read out again later e.g. for campaign tracking.

We found something here, but it doesn't seem to work on instant games.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gamesonfacebook/hosting#queryparams

Can you give me a hint how to add a parameter to the URL, which I can read later again in the instant game iFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The m.me link supports a `ref` param that will be passed to your webhook in the `messaging_optins` and `messaging_referrals` event.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/m-me-links#parameters